# Securing Components at Restlet

Tags: java, security, restlet

I have a restlet (2.2.3) application (I'm new to restlet) which is build up as:

```
component = new Component();
component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, port);
Context childContext = component.getContext().createChildContext();
JaxRsApplication application = new JaxRsApplication(childContext);
application.add(this);
application.setStatusService(new ErrorStatusService());
childContext.getAttributes().put(MY_SERVER, this);     
component.getDefaultHost().attach(application);
```

It runs as a standalone java application. I would like to add security into it. Here is the basic authentication code from [restlet authentication documentation](https://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/core/security/authentication):

```
// Guard the restlet with BASIC authentication.
ChallengeAuthenticator guard = new ChallengeAuthenticator(null, ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "testRealm");
// Instantiates a Verifier of identifier/secret couples based on a simple Map.
MapVerifier mapVerifier = new MapVerifier();
// Load a single static login/secret pair.
mapVerifier.getLocalSecrets().put("login", "secret".toCharArray());
guard.setVerifier(mapVerifier);

guard.setNext(restlet);    

Component component = new Component();  
component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);  
component.getDefaultHost().attachDefault(guard);
```

How can I integrate that security mechanism into my current code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your Restlet application as next element for the guard. This way the application will be the next element in the processing chaining and be called if the authentication is successful.

```
// Guard the restlet with BASIC authentication.
ChallengeAuthenticator guard = new ChallengeAuthenticator(null, 
                         ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "testRealm");
// Instantiates a Verifier of identifier/secret couples based on a simple Map.
MapVerifier mapVerifier = new MapVerifier();
// Load a single static login/secret pair.
mapVerifier.getLocalSecrets().put("login", "secret".toCharArray());
guard.setVerifier(mapVerifier);

// Application
JaxRsApplication application = new JaxRsApplication(childContext);
application.add(this);
application.setStatusService(new ErrorStatusService());

// Set application within guard
guard.setNext(application); // <--------

// Create and configure component
Component component = new Component();  
component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);  
component.getDefaultHost().attachDefault(guard);
```